# how to test model in zend project

Tags: php, zend-framework, testing, phpunit

I want to know how to test the models in zend framework, I already test a controller in zend project.

my phpunit.xml is:

```
<phpunit bootstrap="./bootstrap.php"  colors="true">         
    <testsuite>
        <directory>./</directory>       
    </testsuite>
    <filter>
        <whitelist>
            <directory suffix="MyApp.php">../application/</directory>
            <exclude>
                <file>../application/Bootstrap.php</file>
                <file>../application/controllers/ErrorController.php</file>
                <directory suffix=".phtml">../application/</directory>
            </exclude>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>


    <logging>
        <log type="coverage-html" target="./log/report" charset="UTF-8"
            yui="true" highlight="true" lowUpperBound="50" highLowerBound="80"/>
        <log type="testdox-html" target="./log/testdox.html" />
    </logging>         
</phpunit>
```

the bootstrap.php is under the same folder as phpunit.xml

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// Define path to application directory
defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
    || define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../application'));

// Define application environment
defined('APPLICATION_ENV')
    || define('APPLICATION_ENV', (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'testing'));

// Ensure library/ is on include_path
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'),
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../tests'),
    get_include_path(),
)));

require_once 'Zend/Application.php';
require_once './application/controllers/ControllerTestCase.php';
```

the ControllerTestCase.php is:

```
<?php
    require_once 'Zend/Application.php';
    require_once 'Zend/Test/PHPUnit/ControllerTestCase.php';

    class ControllerTestCase 
        extends Zend_Test_PHPUnit_ControllerTestCase 
    {
        protected $application;

        public function setUp() {
            $this->bootstrap = array($this,'appBootstrap');
            parent::setUp();

        }

        public function appBootstrap() {
            $this->application = 
                new Zend_Application(APPLICATION_ENV,
                                     APPLICATION_PATH.'/configs/application.ini');

            $this->application->bootstrap();


        }
    }
```

I used a ControllerTestCase as a base, and write a test case for the controller, and it works,but I do not know how to write test case for models, the test case for model should also extends ControllerTestCase? or it should extends Zend_Test_PHPUnit_Db? And since the model will connect to database, so how can I test it? can anyone help me on this? for example I have a model:

```
<?php class Application_Model_User2 extends Custom_Model_Base {
public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    static function create(array $data) {
        return parent::_create(
                $_table,
                get_class(),
                $data,
                self::$_columns,
                true
        );
    }
}
```

how to test it?

Answer (score 1):

They should extend `PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase` and not `ControllerTestCase`.

Your testing the Model as a unit of functionality and not a controller, so the Model is a standalone piece of code which should be able to operate separately from your application and it's controllers.

You are not testing the database specifically so you do not need to extend `Zend_Test_PHPUnit_Db`.

Your PHPUnit set up should be sufficient to start your application, so that Zend and any autoloader is configured in order for your Model to be loaded. Your test classes should then just test elements of the Model's code and nothing else from your application.

**EDIT**

So consider you have the following function to test, within the class `Application_Model_User2`:

```
static function find($name, $order=null, $limit=null, $offset=null)
{ 
     return self::_selectAndBind(get_class(), 
                                 self::getDefaultAdapter()
                                 ->select()
                                 ->from($_table)
                                 ->where('name = ?', array($name))
                                 ->order($order)
                                 ->limit($limit, $offset)
                               ); 
}
```

Within your test class which extends `PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase`, here is a [how-to](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.2/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html) and the [docs](http://pear.php.net/reference/PHPUnit-1.0.0alpha3/phpunit.framework/PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase.html) and [Asset Functions](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.2/en/api.html), you might have something like this:

```
require_once 'PHPUnit/Framework.php';

class Application_Model_User2Test extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testFind()
    {
         // Get a result from the function we are testing
         $result = Application_Model_User2::find("foo", "date", 10, 0);

         // Test that there are 10 results
         $this->assertEquals(10, count($result));        
    }

}
```

You could also use functions like `assertGreaterThan()` to determine if the order was correct.

**Note.** This is only a simple example.

Comment: hi, Jake, thank you for your answer, but the model are connected to database, it will do some operation to the database, and the PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase is enough?

Comment: Yes ratzip. `PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase` is the basic test case and gives you access to PHPUnit's testing functions, your not specifically testing the database here your testing the model so the basic testing functions will be fine. To clear this up properly it would be good to know what in the you want to test?

Comment: the project contains several models, each model extends a base model,
these model contains method which will insert,delete, update, and query  entries in a database, I want to test these method

Comment: For example, I want to test whether it's query function works, so I want to test whether it can find some certain user in the database, and check against to the expected value.
Jake, can you provide some example? now I am confusing about it

Comment: for example: I want to test the following function:
 static function find($name, $order=null, $limit=null, $offset=null) {
        return self::_selectAndBind(
                get_class(),
                        self::getDefaultAdapter()
                        ->select()
                        ->from($_table)
                        ->where('name = ?', array($name))
                        ->order($order)
                        ->limit($limit, $offset)
        );
    }
how do I test it?